# Slide down with fadeIn using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Table is sliding from right when check box is checked, and from left to right when check box is unchecked. How to make it slide from up to down or down to up?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {    
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            $('#loaddiv').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');                    
            });
            $('#tbdata').hide(2500);//this code casing slide from right to left
        }
        else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
            $('#loaddiv').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
            $('#tbdata').show(2500);// this code causing slide from right to left
        }
    });
});
```

Check herer http://jsfiddle.net/z7rgsduv/

Comment: Can you show a working example of this code in a http://jsfiddle.net. I see no reason for this code to make anything slide?

Comment: if you observe `$('#tbdata').show(2500);`, the delay here is causing that for table. you can ignore the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {

        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            $('#loaddiv').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
                
            });
            $('#tbdata').show();
            $('#tbdata').animate({top:0})
        }
        else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
            $('#loaddiv').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
           $('#tbdata').animate({top:-25},function(){
             $(this).hide()
            })
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#tbdata{
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div id ="divloading" style="width:100%; height:100%">
             <img id="loaddiv" src="http://www.degruyterfabriek.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/DGF_Redactie.jpg" style="width:200px"  />
             <div id="div1" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden">
               <table id="tbdata" >
                  <tr>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                 <p><input type="checkbox" />Click to hide details</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I want to slide up the table only `$('#tbdata').show(2500);` and not the loading dive.